# kentico version 9 locking publish to certain users

Tags: content-management-system, roles, kentico

I have looked around quite a bit, and understand workflow, and putting steps in place in terms od content editing but cannot see anywhere how I restrict roles to steps.
In short I want the bulk of my users to be able to edit and then submit for approval but not be able to publish (save).
Then I need a couple of 'global/super' users to be the only ones who are able to approve and then publish the content live.
This will apply to new pages, edits to existing, everything basically.
Users who can edit and save for approval.
The super users who can publish if they approve.

Answer (score 1):

In the *Workflow* application there is *Security* tab per each step - advanced workflow only **OR** security tab for each **custom** step in basic workflow.

You can learn more here:
[Configuring workflow step permissions](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Configuring+workflow+step+permissions)

Advanced workflow:

[image]

Basic publishing with custom step:

[image]

Comment: Brilliant, thank you works exactly as I need it. Thank you! :)